# Strange behaviour while saving text from CKEditor to phpobjects in php

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am using ckeditor to edit a model description fields.
While updating the data when I make a submit request I see a strange behaviour.

I was using `set_value('description')` to set the value of the description from WYSIWYG to a value against php object key.

So when this `set_value('description')` was called for first time it

> `&lt;p&gt;Testing&lt;/p&gt;`

Instead of saving it like

> `<p>Testing</p>`

But when i call the same method again i.e. `set_value('description')` it returns expected output i.e. `<p>Testing</p>`

Now when I have switched to `$_POST['description']` and it works as expected.

What is happening here?

Comment: Probably, ```htmlspecialchars``` is having some effects in there.

Answer (score 1):

The CI function set_value() has a third parameter, which prevents an html string to be escaped twice.

[Usage example](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value): `set_value('description','a_value', false)`

what is happening here (CI 3.x):

if the 3rd parameter is not set to false, *system/helpers/form_helper.php* near line 712 has the function `set_value()` calling the function `html_escape($value)`, which you find in *system/core/Common.php* near line 735 and which returns a HTML escaped variable.